# No type errors reported when list literal has elements not matching declared generic type. Why?

Tags: generics, dart, typechecking

I have been making my way through Shailen Tuli's collection of of snippets in [Dart By Example](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_by_example), when I came across the following code:

```dart
List<String> fruits = [
  {'name': 'apple', 'selected': true},
  {'name': 'banana', 'selected': true},
  {'name': 'kiwi', 'selected': false}
 ];
```

Notice that `fruits` is declared to be a `List<String>` but that the list elements are actually maps.

**Question: Why is there no type error being reported?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code example had been written in a strongly statically typed language then an error would be reported. But **Dart** is a:

- **Dynamically typed** language with
- Static type checking based an "**optimistic system of type heuristics**" <sup>1</sup>.

Consider this declaration:

```dart
List<num> lst = [4, "ty-two"];
```

It is important to understand that the array literal `[4, "ty-two"]`, as given, is of type `List<dynamic>`, where `dynamic` is the **static type** attributed to an expression when the static type system does not know what it is (e.g., the user did not declare a static type), or doesn't want to bother doing a deeper analysis to figure out what the type might be -- as is the case for the generic parameter to the list `lst`.

The static type system can only help point out that there is a type error if you declare the expected static type of the literal list's elements like this:

```dart
List<num> lst = <num>[4, "tytoo"];
List<String> fruits = <Map>[{'name': 'apple', ...}, ...];
```

Now, in both cases a type error is reported. In the case of `lst` the optimistic system can easily tell that the `String` `"ty-two"` can never be of type `num`. Similar remarks apply for `fruits`. On the other hand if we had

```dart
var a = "tytoo";
List<num> lst = <num>[4, a];
```

To declare a variable with a `var` effectively means (to the static type checker) that `a` is of type `dynamic`. Hence, no error is reported in the assignment to `lst`.

Details are given in the [Language Specification](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/) and these two (IMHO) **excellent articles**; they explain typing in Dart while also covering the **rationale** behind the language design decisions that were taken relative to the type system.

--

<sup>1</sup> https://www.dartlang.org/articles/why-dart-types/
<sup>2</sup> https://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/